# jaxb marshalling LocalDate with custom date format

Tags: java, jaxb, localdate

i followed a topic here but it doesnt answer my question.
I want the soap response to format the localdate to the same localdate in the soap request.

for example: my localdate request: 10/10/1990
response needs to be 10/10/1990 but i always get 1990-10-10 because toString formats it that way...

my code:

```
public class LocalDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate> {

public DateTimeFormatter dateFormat() {
    //DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[MM/dd/yyyy][MM-dd-yyyy][yyyy/MM/dd][yyyy-MM-dd]");    

    DateTimeFormatter mmddyyyySlash = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    DateTimeFormatter mmddyyyy = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
    DateTimeFormatter yyyymmdd = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTimeFormatter yyyymmddSlash = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");    

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendOptional(mmddyyyySlash)
            .appendOptional(mmddyyyy)
            .appendOptional(yyyymmdd)
            .appendOptional(yyyymmddSlash)
            .toFormatter();

    return formatter;
}

public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = dateFormat();
    return LocalDate.parse(v, formatter);
}

public String marshal(LocalDate v) throws Exception {
    return v.toString();
}
}
```

how can i resolve that?
i tried to:

```
public String marshal(LocalDate v) throws Exception {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = dateFormat();
    String ld = v.format(formatter);

    return ld;
}
```

but the result:
05/05/199005-05-19901990-05-051990/05/05
:(

Answer (score 2):

Try using your `dateFormat()` method.  You can run this to see how it works.  I simplified it a little bit.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

public class LocalDateAdapter {

    public DateTimeFormatter dateFormat() {
        DateTimeFormatter mmddyyyySlash = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                             .appendOptional(mmddyyyySlash).toFormatter();
        return formatter;
    }

    public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = dateFormat();
        return LocalDate.parse(v, formatter);
    }

    public String marshal(LocalDate v) {
        return v.format(dateFormat());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

        LocalDateAdapter adapter = new LocalDateAdapter();
        String dateAsString = adapter.marshal(date);
        System.out.println("Date as String: " + dateAsString);

        LocalDate dateAsDate = adapter.unmarshal(dateAsString);
        System.out.println("Date back as LocalDate: " + adapter.marshal(dateAsDate));

    }
}
```

**Edit**

Updated to show how the `marshall()` and `unmarshall()` can be used to indicate proper preservation of the date information.

This now prints out:

```
Date as String: 07/05/2019
Date back as LocalDate: 07/05/2019
```

**Update**

Here's an example of how to use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` to distinguish when to use one adapter type vs another for different date formats.

Without knowing the broader system context, this is one way you could enforce which formatter to use.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

class DateWithSlashAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate> {

    public DateTimeFormatter dateFormat() {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = dateFormat();
        return LocalDate.parse(v, formatter);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDate v) {
        return v.format(dateFormat());
    }
}

class DateWithHyphenAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate> {

    public DateTimeFormatter dateFormat() {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy");
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = dateFormat();
        return LocalDate.parse(v, formatter);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDate v) {
        return v.format(dateFormat());
    }
}

/** Example of a class representing your SOAP payload */
class SoapRequestExample {
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateWithSlashAdapter.class)
    LocalDate someDateWithSlashes;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateWithHyphenAdapter.class)
    LocalDate someDateWithHyphens;
}
```

Comment: that works only to one format... if i add another one, for example:
DateTimeFormatter mmddyyyy = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
and append it to "formatter" i will get: 05/05/199005-05-1990 
:(

Comment: @TiagoMachado In the original post, `marshal()` is always a result formatted in ISO-8601 because it was just returning `toString()` on the date.  You need to use a formatter corresponding to the desired format to get it to print differently.  However, your comment suggests you have a higher-level requirement to track the original date format to use in deciding which output to format.  That's a little more involved and depends on the surrounding context where you're handling these messages.  But I'll come up with a simplistic example of what I mean.

Comment: That's a pretty good answer but there is a problem, I have 1 field:
private LocalDate birthdate;
so, when i do my request i can type what ever date format i want.
and when i use the service to get the data from the person that has the birthdate it should give me in the format of the request i did.
it should work using just 1 field... :(